# Java unable to extend ByteBuffer class

Tags: java, abstract-class, bytebuffer

I was trying to extend ByteBuffer class to add a "getString" method to it. But I just can't make it work.

My class is also abstract. When I extend it I see an error "There is no default constructor available in java.nio.ByteBuffer". And I `think` I understand why that happens as there is no public constructor in ByteBuffer class.

So how do I extend it? How can I add functionality to it?

Comment: OK, there *are no accessible ctors in ByteBuffer at all.*  You can't do that.  Classes with only private ctors are not extensible.  It's the same as a final class.

Comment: Well I did not add my own constructor as I don't need one. I'm only adding one method. I tried calling my super class constructor but another error appears saying I can't access it from outside of its package

Answer (score 3):

You cannot extend `ByteBuffer`. Although it is not a final class, all it's constructors are package-private, which means that it can only be extended by classes in the same package (`java.nio`). The reason for this is that all constructors of a sub-class always need to call one constructor of the super class, and your class is not allowed to call any one of them.

If you want a special buffer, you need to directly extend `Buffer`, although I would not recommend this. Instead, the best solution for you is probably to write a wrapper class that delegates the methods you need to a `ByteBuffer` instance, or just put your `getString` method in another class.

Comment: i was afraid that this is the case... I will look into these wrapper classes. I considered putting it in another class but it just doesn't _feel_ right.